# Rescuing a DivisionByZero with default value returns NaN in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would expect the begin rescue to set ratio to zero but instead it gets set to `NaN` which is incredibly frustrating when I am rescuing the error to provide a default value.

```
  ratio = begin
            0.0 / 0.0
          rescue ZeroDivisionError
            0
          end

  ratio = 0 if ratio.nan?
```

The code I would like to get rid of is the `ratio = 0 if ratio.nan?` why is that needed?

**Edit**
new code looks like:

```
  ratio = bet_money_amount_cents.to_f / total_amount.to_f
  ratio.nan? ? 0 : ratio
```

Comment: I am fine with your new edits

Comment: `ratio = bet_money_amount_cents.to_f / total_amount.to_f rescue 0` if you are comfortable with an inline rescue

Comment: @Stefan `bet_money_amount_cents.to_f / total_amount.to_f` wouldn't produce any error the way OP looking for. OP's just to avoid `NaN`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit of course, you're right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `0.0 / 0.0` not raising the error(`ZeroDivisionError`), you are thinking for.

[`ZeroDivisionError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/ZeroDivisionError.html) is *Raised when attempting to divide an integer by 0*.

```
42 / 0
#=> ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
```

**Note** that only division by an exact `0` will raise the exception:

```
42 /  0.0 #=> Float::INFINITY
42 / -0.0 #=> -Float::INFINITY
0  /  0.0 #=> NaN
```

I would write as below :

```
ratio = bet_money_amount_cents.to_f / total_amount.to_f
ratio = 0 if ratio.nan?
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `0.0 / 0.0` yields `Float::NAN` (Nan) instead of throwing `ZeroDivisionError` exception (unlike `0 / 0`)

```
0.0 / 0.0
# => NaN
0.0 / 0
# => NaN
0 / 0
# ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
#         from (irb):17:in `/'
#         from (irb):17
#         from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

According to [`ZeroDivisionError` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ZeroDivisionError.html):

> Raised when attempting to divide an **integer** by 0.

Comment: I beat you by 29 seconds... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code:

```
ratio = total_amount == 0 ? 0 : bet_money_amount_cents.to_f / total_amount
```